# mathematica example for parallel run

Tags: parallelization, scripting, high-performance-clusters

I want to run a parallel mathematica example via a PBS script. I am not expert in this application, instead as a system administrator, I have to be sure that users are able to submit parallel jobs to the cluster.

I saw an example [here](https://wiki.hpcc.msu.edu/display/hpccdocs/Using+Mathematica+in+Batch+Mode) and as you can see it uses 4 cores of a node. Is there any `.m` file for testing that?

```
#PBS -N Mathematica-4thr
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=4,mem=2gb,walltime=00:10:00
module load Mathematica

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
math -noprompt -run '<<pi.m'
```

Thanks in advance...